# When using a helper service to access my API to retrieve 1 record, I am getting nulls and nothing is displayed

Tags: angular, typescript

I am in the process of learning Angular and .Net Core, and to try and simplify my code I have decided to use a helper service to hold API calls that will be used in multiple components.

When I am trying to retrieve all records it works correctly, however when I try to use the same process to retrieve 1 record, I get console errors and the object I'm using returns as a null.

Below is the code from my working methods when I retrieve all records:

User Component

```
getUsers() {
  this.selectedUser = null;
  this.hasSelectedUser = false;
  this.helper.getUsers((data: any) => { this.users = data; });
}
```

Helper Service

```
private getUsersRequest(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'users');
}

public getUsers(callback: any ) {
  this.getUsersRequest().subscribe(response => {
    this.users = response;
    this.users.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      return a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName);
    });
    callback(this.users);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

The above works well, however the below doesn't:

User Component

```
getDetails(userId: number) {
  this.helper.getUser((data: any) => { this.selectedUser = data; }, userId);
}
```

The user Id comes from the user that is selected in the web page.

Helper service

```
private getUserRequest(id: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + id);
}

public getUser(callback: any, id: number ) {
  this.getUserRequest(id).subscribe(response => {
    this.user = response;
    callback(this.user);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

I can see that the helper service retrieves the data when I console.log the user object from the helper service, but nothing seems to be coming through to the component.

NOTE: if I don't use the helper service to retrieve the single record it works fine, but I would like to use the helper service if possible

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could solve your problem but instead of a callback fucntion you should use observables so this

```
public getUser(callback: any, id: number ) {
  this.getUserRequest(id).subscribe(response => {
    this.user = response;
    callback(this.user);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

becomes this

```
public getUser(id: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.getUserRequest(id).pipe(
            map(response => {
                this.user = response;
                return response;
            })
        );
    }
```

and this

```
getDetails(userId: number) {
  this.helper.getUser((data: any) => { this.selectedUser = data; }, userId);
}
```

should become this

```
getDetails(userId: number) {
  this.helper.getUser(userId).subscribe((data: any) => { this.selectedUser = data});
}
```